# What are Extra Jumbo Frets?

Tags: electric-guitar, fretboard, metal

So I've been looking around Shechter guitars and some guitars there have X-Jumbo frets, for example https://www.schecterguitars.com/guitars/banshee-mach-7-detail

From what I've gathered Jumbo frets come in few sizes, but non of the documentation I've searched contained a word about X-Jumbo. Is X-Jumbo just a synonym for the 6100 Jumbo frets which to my understanding are the biggest ones?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like medium / jumbo / extra jumbo / whatever is not really standardized, so each guitar maker more or less does its own thing. 6100’s are for example really large, so although Dunlop calls them "Jumbo" many guitar builders and fret wire brands will use smaller sizes for what they call jumbo. Of course that also depends on the neck geometry.

So you’d need to ask Schecter guitars what sizes they use. That being said, the largest fretwire by Dunlop and what they consider extra jumbo would be 6000, which is 0.07mm higher and 0.2mm wider than 6100s.